# pipe cmdlet output into a variable and a csv file

Tags: powershell

Currently I am doing this in my PowerShell script:

```
$ServiceTagsPath=$filePath + '\DellAPIWarrantyLIST.csv'

write-host 'get all computer names from Active Directory...for Windows 7...'
Get-ADComputer -properties * -filter {(operatingsystem -like "*Windows 7*")} |
    Where-Object {$_.name -like "*-*"} |
    Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "V7-*"} |
    Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "*-NONE"} |
    Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "*-ONCALL"} |
    Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "*-BLACKBAUD"} |
    Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "SC-WIN7-1"} |
    Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "UT-SWCLIENT-01"} |
    Select-Object -property Name , LastLogonDate | export-csv $ServiceTagsPath -NoTypeInformation -Force 

$computers= Get-ADComputer -properties * -filter {(operatingsystem -like "*Windows 7*")} |
    Where-Object {$_.name -like "*-*"} |
    Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "V7-*"} |
    Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "*-NONE"} |
    Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "*-ONCALL"} |
    Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "*-BLACKBAUD"} |
    Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "SC-WIN7-1"} |
    Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "UT-SWCLIENT-01"} |
    Select-Object -Expand Name                           

Write-Host $computers.Length + ' computers found in Active Directory...'
```

The first one gives me a csv file with 2 columns, and about 1500 records, the second one gives me an array variable which I use in web-service calls to an API...

But would it be possible to do both in one step?
is there a way to do both of these in one so as well as having a csv file with 2 columns, showing the Computer Name and LastLogondate, I'd have an array with just the computer names?

Comment: Why not just use one Get-ADComputer query ($computers, take off the Select-Object statement) and then do whatever you need to with that. Searching AD 2x just to output it differently seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply assign **all** the results of `Get-ADComputer` to a variable (without using `Select-Object`):

```
$computers = Get-ADComputer -properties * -filter {(operatingsystem -like "*Windows 7*")} |
    Where-Object {$_.name -like "*-*"} |
    Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "V7-*"} |
    Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "*-NONE"} |
    Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "*-ONCALL"} |
    Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "*-BLACKBAUD"} |
    Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "SC-WIN7-1"} |
    Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "UT-SWCLIENT-01"}
```

Then use that variable as the input for your two commands:

```
$ServiceTagsPath = "$filePath\DellAPIWarrantyLIST.csv"
$computers | Select-Object -Property Name,LastLogonDate | Export-Csv $ServiceTagsPath -NoTypeInformation -Force

$computer_names = $computers | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

Comment: `Where-Object` is slower than filtering in the query. You also don't need `-Properties *` since `Select-Object` is only selecting the `Name` and `LastLogonDate` properties.

Answer (score 4):

It is much more efficient to query for what you want instead of retrieving everything and filtering after-the-fact with `Where-Object`. You also don't need `-Properties *`. Example:

```
$outputFilename = Join-Path $filePath "DellAPIWarrantyLIST.csv"
Get-ADComputer -LDAPFilter "(&(operatingSystem=*Windows 7*)(name=*-*)(!name=*-none)(!name=*-oncall)(!name=*-blackbaud)(!name=sc-win7-1)(!name=ut-swclient-01))" -Property LastLogonDate |
  Select-Object Name,LastLogonDate |
  Export-Csv $outputFilename -NoTypeInformation
$outputCount = (Import-Csv $outputFilename | Measure-Object).Count
Write-Host ("Found {0} computer(s)" -f $outputCount)
if ( $outputCount -eq 0 ) {
  Remove-Item $outputFilename
}
```

Comment: This is much faster, filter prior instead of after.

Comment: @BillStewart: Thanks for this, much appreciated to learn something new!

Comment: @Bill_Stewart: Is it easy to modify the `LDAP Query` to return all operating Systems *Windows 7* and above?

Answer (score 1):

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$ServiceTagsPath=$filePath + '\DellAPIWarrantyLIST.csv'

Write-Host 'Getting all Windows 7 Computer Names from Active Directory. Please wait...'

$computers= Get-ADComputer -properties * -filter {(operatingsystem -like "*Windows 7*")} |
    Where-Object {$_.name -like "*-*"} |
    Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "V7-*"} |
    Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "*-NONE"} |
    Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "*-ONCALL"} |
    Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "*-BLACKBAUD"} |
    Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "SC-WIN7-1"} |
    Where-Object {$_.name -NotLike "UT-SWCLIENT-01"}

#console output
$computers | select Name
#csv output
$computers | Select Name, LastlogonDate | Export-Csv $ServiceTagsPath -NoTypeInformation

Write-Host $computers.Length + ' computers found in AD...'
```