# LDAP Query for Active-Directory Get-ADComputer in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap

I have the below LDAP query (from [my previous question answered by Bill_Stewart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49881519/pipe-cmdlet-output-into-a-variable-and-a-csv-file)) in my script that returns all computers from `Get-ADComputer` for Windows 7, with some exclusions.

```
$computersFilter= "(&(operatingSystem=*Windows 7*)(name=*-*)(!name=V7-*)(!name=*-none)(!name=*-oncall)(!name=*-blackbaud)(!name=sc-win7-1)(!name=ut-swclient-01))"
```

and it works fine with the below call to `Get-ADComputer`:

```
$computers= Get-ADComputer -LDAPFilter $computersFilter -Property LastLogonDate | Select-Object Name,LastLogonDate 
$computers | Select Name, LastlogonDate | Export-Csv $ServiceTagsPath -NoTypeInformation
```

However, I want to have my query return all computers with Windows 7 **and above** but when I change it like so:

```
(&(operatingSystem=*Windows 7*)(operatingSystem=*Windows 8*)(operatingSystem=*Windows 10*)
```

nothing is returned into the `$computers` variable.

So what's the right way to write an LDAP query to return all operating system versions Windows 7 and above?

Comment: Haven't used LDAP before, but it looks like you want an OR here, not an AND.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some help from Rob in the comments, and some more research, I found that the correct way is to use `OR`, and the operator is `|`

like so:

```
$computersFilter= "(&(|(operatingSystem=*Windows 7*)"
$computersFilter+= "(operatingSystem=*Windows 8*)"
$computersFilter+= "(operatingSystem=*Windows 8.1*)"
$computersFilter+= "(operatingSystem=*Windows 10*))"
$computersFilter+= "(name=*-*)(!name=V7-*)(!name=*-none)(!name=*-oncall)"
$computersFilter+= "(!name=*-blackbaud)(!name=sc-win7-1)(!name=ut-swclient-01))" 

$computers= Get-ADComputer -LDAPFilter $computersFilter 
-Property * | Select-Object Name, OperatingSystem, LastLogonDate 

$computers | Select Name, OperatingSystem, LastLogonDate | 
Export-Csv $ServiceTagsPath -NoTypeInformation
```

References:

[IBM LDAP Search Filter Expressions](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYJ99_8.5.0/admin-system/rbug_ldapfltrxprns.html)

[MSDN - LDAP Query Basics](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996205%28v=exchg.65%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)